# How to fetch one object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I am using get method axios fetching from localhost api and i want to fetch only one set of object fetch[console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2C2T.jpg)

There is 0:1:2: with object i just want to fetch one set of object  i.e {player:, channelname:,ip:,port}
Any method to fetch that?

Comment: This is probably appropriate: https://dev.to/m_adams1909/data-fetching-with-axios-in-react-made-simple-2jei

Comment: In console log there is 4 api fetch but want 1 .How i do that? Because when I mapping, all data fetch inside table

Comment: If you here place your code, I or others can better help you. I didn't work with Axios, for the same I placed a link to it. I worked with fetch.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hoover-4psg4 link of full code

Comment: In your code, It should not be e.g [Postdata, setpostData] instead [setpostData, Postdata]? Also see use from 'fetch' and 'map' in my code.https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-tree-ru75q?file=/src/App.js